# REGEX para extraer la cuarta palabra de una cadena separada por _

Tags: regular, expresion

Estoy intentando obtener el la cuarta palabara de una cadena de palabras separadas por `_`

Por ejemplo tengo:

```
MEXICO_SAS_DS_FINANZAS_R24_R2422
MEXICO_SAS_DS_FINANZAS_R24_Insumos
MEXICO_SAS_DS_ARPYMES_MPROD
MEXICO_SAS_DS_RC2_ASMD_Proyect_Proyect_Workspaces_EMWS2
```

Me interesa obtener la cuarta palabra es decir:

```
FINANZAS
ARPYMES
RC2
```

Intente con:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(ds_name, 'DS_(.*)_')
```

Pero no lo consigo.
Ojala alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola Marco. ¿Que lenguaje de programación utilizas? ¿Tiene que ser si o si una RegEx? ¿Todas las cadenas empiezan siempre igual?

Comment: Creo que el problema, es que el "." dentro () apunta a todo, "_" incluido, prueba DS_([A_Z]*) por ejemplo, dando por supuesto que las palabras siempre están en mayúsculas.

Answer (score 0):

De tu código intuyo que en realidad lo que buscas es lo que le sucede a `DS_` y que tu problema es que te está entregando:

```
DS_FINANZAS_R24_
DS_ARPYMES_
DS_RC2_ASMD_Proyect_Proyect_Workspaces_
```

Y es que `DS_(.*)_` es demasiado ambicioso, por lo que buscará el máximo posible. Yo cambiaría el `.*` que busca cualquier carácter repetido (incluyendo el `_`) 0 o más veces, por `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` que busca cualquier carácter alfanumérico que se repite 1 o más veces

De esta manera ya tienes algo más cercano `DS_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_`, cuyo resultado es:

```
DS_FINANZAS_
DS_FINANZAS_
DS_ARPYMES_
DS_RC2_
```

Luego para buscar lo que precede se usa `Lookahead` -> `(?<=ALGO)` y lo que antecede `lookbehind` -> `(?=ALGO)`. La combinación de ambos se denomina `Lookaround`

Entonces para buscar todo lo que está después de `DS_` y que sea alfa numérico sin contar el `_`

```
(?<=DS_)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Demo

```js
let regex = /(?<=DS_)[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g


pruebas = [
"MEXICO_SAS_DS_FINANZAS_R24_R2422",
"MEXICO_SAS_DS_FINANZAS_R24_Insumos",
"MEXICO_SAS_DS_ARPYMES_MPROD",
"MEXICO_SAS_DS_RC2_ASMD_Proyect_Proyect_Workspaces_EMWS2"]; 

for (let p of pruebas) {
    console.log(p.match(regex));
}
```

Comment: ¿Le será útil en su DBMS? (ya que mencionó `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, a pesar de no haber mencionado qué DBMS es)